# Word for "someone who injects themselves into conversations"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

I'm trying to think of a word for someone who injects themselves into conversations. Typically in an uninvited manner.

You know the guy that comes over when you're talking to someone else and stands around until he can join the conversation.

*Nosy* isn't quite right.

Comment: All the answers seem rather negative, but I know there are plenty of situations where this is acceptable, normal, or even the only way to join a group. Unless you're talking about someone who does it _too much_, in which case, carry on. :)

Comment: imposing? "take advantage of someone by demanding their attention or commitment."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word **meddlesome**  would fit your description

Person who intervenes officiously or indiscreetly in the affairs of others is  meddlesome.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I'm pretty certain "busybody" is more natural than "meddler" when you're talking about someone jumping in to conversations.  Meddlesome carries a more serious connotation.

Comment: Perhaps, but the OED gives _meddlesome_ only as an adjective, so you can't say someone is _a meddlesome_.

Comment: I want the connotation. *busybody* doesn't carry enough. The fact that most other suggestions contain *meddle* in the definition, implies that *meddle* is at the core of my question.

Answer (score 13):

[Buttinsky](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buttinsky) works pretty well, and also just sounds amusing.  :)

As mentioned in other answers, *busybody* is good, *nosy parker* works but might not be as universally recognized.  (I've never heard it in the US.)

Comment: + *buttinsky*, funny.

Comment: +1. The OED has an entry for _buttinsky_, which it describes as ‘slang, originally US’. One of the citations is from P G Wodehouse, who spells it _buttinski_.

Answer (score 4):

I would say Busybody. A busybody is someone who repeatedly gets into other peoples affairs, and that would apply to someone who is constantly going into other people's conversations.

Comment: But this isn't quite the person described in the OP's question, is it?

Comment: Technically, by extension, it is. But if he wants the clear and simple answer, meddlesome is perfect.

Comment: I tend to think of a 'busybody' as a person who goes out of their way to involve themselves in someone's affairs under the pretext of trying to help them. That seems to me far more than we have here, namely someone who butts in uninvited into other people's conversations (perhaps ignoring body-language signs that he is not wanted).  My proposed answer below, is 'socially imposing'.

Answer (score 4):

Someone who butts in on a conversation is a ***nosy parker*** or a ***stickybeak.***

Comment: *nosy* isn't quite right. *stickybeak* is better though.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary [Nosy parker](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nosey%20parker) is a phrase disinct from just nosy, and it carries pretty much the same meaning as stickybeak.  (Beak as in nose!)

Answer (score 3):

How about an **interjector**?

I know it sounds like some kind of robot warrior, but literally it means:

> Someone who interrupts

Answer (score 1):

Try *officious* — that might be what you're going for.  Butting in and offering help where it's not wanted, etc.

Answer (score 1):

***Interfering*** My ex-mother-in-law was a prime example. She never minded her own business, always butted in conversations, and gave her unsolicited opinion on everything.

[Interfering](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interfering); *3. To intervene or intrude in the affairs of others; meddle.*

Answer (score 1):

How about **interloper**?

> a person who becomes involved in a place or situation where they are not wanted or are considered not to belong.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single word, but if you can cope with two, I would venture 'socially imposing' as the most apt description.