# Idiom for a person who gets involved in a situation that is completely irrelevant to them?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom which can be used in the following scenarios:

- To refer to a person who is involved in a discussion that does not concern him/her
- To refer to a person who goes somewhere they are not supposed to be

Example sentences:

> — Who was that guy on the scientific panel?
> — No idea, he looked like a ______. I’m pretty sure he’s not even a scientist.

> So that guy just went into her house along with everyone else like a _______.

Comment: I wouldn't use the same terms in both situations. For the first, see [What word describes someone who offers unsolicited advice?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/79844/191178)

Comment: @Laurel I see, but what I was after something different; I have edited the question.

Comment: A person who attends a social function to which they have not been invited can be called a _gate-crasher_.

Comment: Informally a *buttinski* or *buttinsky*

Comment: busybody or nosy parker only ones I could find, sure does seem there should be more idioms for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word or phrase for people butting in and taking a side in an online conversation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246568/word-or-phrase-for-people-butting-in-and-taking-a-side-in-an-online-conversation) Or, for a word, [word for someone who injects themselves into conversations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137164/word-for-someone-who-injects-themselves-into-conversations/137249#1372490)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My question is not limited to conversations. Please see the second example sentence.

Comment: I'd say these are essentially different questions (and David M agrees), though 'interloper' (given in the duplicate of one of them) works up to a point.

Comment: The so-called duplicate does not even deal with obvious candidates such as *bystander*, *passer-by*, *add-on*, *supernumerary* kand others. Leave open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found something which fits, especially in the first sentence.

The idiom is **a square peg in a round hole**. [According to Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20square%20peg%20in%20a%20round%20hole), it means

> someone who does not fit in a particular place or situation.

The example given is as follows.

> She felt like a square peg in a round hole at the new school until she made some new friends.

Comment: But neither does this totally answer your question. It doesn't work for 'a person who is [gets] involved in a discussion that does not concern him/her'. And the idiom 'a square peg in a round hole' has been given many times before on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's the closest one.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your first criterion, but about the second one, I think *[interloper](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/interloper)* would be a good fit, even though it is not necessarily an idiom.

> One who intrudes in a place, situation, or activity

By the way, to *lope* is to run or ride with a steady, easy gait. The word *interloper* is therefore kind of idiomatic. An interloper in the discussion that does not concern him or her is just loping along as if there's nothing wrong, pretending they belong in the discussion, despite their presence being neither needed nor appreciated.

> *[Word History](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/interloper)*: The word *interloper* has its origin in the time when England was embarking on the course that would lead to the British Empire. *Interloper* is first recorded in the late 1500s in connection with the Muscovy Company, the earliest major English trading company (chartered in 1555). The word was soon being used in connection with independent traders competing with the East India Company (chartered in 1600). The East India Company was established as a monopoly, and independent traders, called interlopers, were not welcome. The term is probably partly derived from Dutch, the language of one of the great trade rivals of the English at that time. The *inter*- is simply the prefix *inter*-, which English has borrowed from Latin, meaning "between, among." The element -*loper* is probably related to the same element in the word *landloper*, "vagabond," a word adopted from Dutch *landloper*: *land*, plus -*loper*, from *lopen*, "to run, leap." The word *interloper* came to be used by the 1630s in the extended sense of a "meddler, a person who intrudes in others' affairs."*(Minor modifications in this entry are mine.)*

Answer (score 1):

**nosey parker**

or

**busybody**

A nosy parker is someone who doesn't mind their own business. They will poke their noses into other people's affairs, and attempt to eke out whatever information they can, the more personal the better. A busybody is a near equivalent, and perhaps more familiar term to American speakers.
https://itectec.com/englishusage/learn-english-the-inquisitive-tale-of-nosey-parker/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that both of these examples would fit a single word or idiom.  While similar, they're different in nature.

A [***poser***](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/poser) is someone who pretends to be something they're not, generally to gain favor.  It certainly matches your first example.

The second example is more nuanced.  For this I would suggest the above mentioned ***interloper***.  If you're looking for something more poetic, you could use the notion of a [Trojan horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_Horse).

> Metaphorically, a "Trojan horse" has come to mean any trick or stratagem that causes a target to invite a foe into a securely protected bastion or place

Or even less subtly, "He went into her house *as if he belonged*.

Comment: Not mentioning any games here, but "imposter" would be a good answer.